# org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException

Tags: java, apache, maven

В связи с чем может возникать такая ошибка?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project messages: Could not resolve dependencies for project ru.liberty.messages:messages:war:RELEASE: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:8.0.0 -> org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.3.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.3.0: Could not transfer artifact org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:pom:2.3.0 from/to switchboard (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connect to repo1.maven.org:80 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.36.209] failed: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
[11:42:19][Step 1/1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project messages: Could not resolve dependencies for project ru.liberty.messages:messages:war:RELEASE: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:8.0.0 -> org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.3.0
```

зависимости

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: у вас точно есть доступ к репозиторию maven?

Comment: repo1.maven.org открывается?

Comment: да. открывается Index of /
maven2/

Comment: странно у вас в pom 8.2.0 а в ошибке 8.0.0.
попробуйте вручную удалить то что в .m2/repository/org/ ... и собрать заново